# Swift: How to unwrap UITextField Optional String to Float

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I'm making an app, specifically a tip calculator, to practice my Swift skills. Currently using Swift 5.

I've set up the layout, labels, textfields, etc. But one problem I am running into is the optional string from the user input in text field box. I am trying to multiply the user input (String?) with the slider value, which is a Float.

I've tried several ways, force unwrapping, guard statements, if let, and type casting, but everything I get something similar where Xcode won't let me mix two types together. I've also gotten the text field input to an optional Float (Float?) but still, Xcode wants me to find a way to get the two types together.

My text field input box is a variable closure.

```
private let priceTextField: UITextField = {
    let textField                   = UITextField()
    textField.placeholder           = "$00.00"
    textField.textColor             = UIColor.black
    textField.font                  = UIFont.init(name: "HelveticaNeue-Thin", size: 60)
    textField.keyboardType          = UIKeyboardType.numberPad
    textField.textAlignment         = .center
    textField.borderStyle           = UITextField.BorderStyle.roundedRect
    textField.borderStyle           = UITextField.BorderStyle.none
    textField.sizeToFit()
    textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return textField
}()
```

This is my slider action function that will calculate the tip amount.

```
@objc func sliderChange() {
    totalTipAmount.text = (tipSlider.value) * Float(priceTextField.text! as NSString)
    myTipTextView.text = "My Tip (\(Int(tipSlider.value.rounded()))%):"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your calculation seems fine but it might be throwing a compiler error for setting `Float` in place of `String` to `totalTipAmount`. You can try as follows,

```
@objc func sliderChange() {
    guard let priceText = self.priceTextField.text, let price = Float(priceText) else { return }
    totalTipAmount.text = "\(tipSlider.value * price)"
}
```

Comment: Kamran! Thank you again for your help, this solved my problem. I didn't think of using an if let inside of another if let. May I ask why this works instead of a guard let statement? Trying to understand the logic behind it.

Comment: Actually all these lines can be reduced to two lines using guard statement. But i used this so that you can debug easily and find the exact issue if it fails.

Comment: If you don't mind, how would you write the guard statement? I've tried different iterations of a guard statement but keep getting something similar to "Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Float' with an argument list of type '(String?)'"